# Trying to install bosh lite, not able to set the target

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

bosh target 192.168.50.4 lite
Usage: target [] [] [--ca-cert FILE]

$ bosh status
Config
             /Users/laled/.bosh_config

Director
  not set

Deployment
  not set

Comment: check this article for a details - [link](http://elsoufy.blogspot.com/2015/02/installing-cloud-foundry-v2-locally-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

Strange, the command you entered should work.

```
bosh target IP <alias>
```

Perhaps update to latest BOSH CLI version and try again.